# Generate a Precise Amount of Random Data in C#

Tags: c#, string, random, byte

I need a way to generate a precise amount of psuedo-random (string) data. For example, I would like to code a method that takes an argument for the number of bytes to generate and returns a string of that precise size.

I originally intended to simply generate 1 character per byte needed, but apparently characters aren't all a byte anymore.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A string restricted to a specific set of characters?

Comment: _measure an existing string to determine that precise number of bytes_  - again, it ain't all bytes anymore.

Comment: @AlexK. Not really, just random string data.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I need to be able to generate random data, in other words, it must be different each time. So apart from using several mini strings say 10 bytes long and randomly assembling them, that wouldn't work, and that's not a great solution for me.

Comment: A string doesn't contain bytes at all, but characters. A character uses two bytes in memory, but I don't think that's what you are after. You can also encode a string into bytes, but the length differs depending on the encoding used. What is the purpose of getting a string that corresponds (in some way) to a number of bytes? How are you going to use it?

Comment: The relationship between data and text seems a little blurred here. Are the strings the end-result or a means to get bytes?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The strings are the end result.

Comment: OK, and are you size requirements about char-counts or byte-counts?

Comment: @Guffa I think modern encodings like unicode and utf-8 actually are viably sized. (Not all characters take up the same amount of space. It's a bit hard to explain how I'm using it, but the random data is put into files to serve as placeholders for real data.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the end result (the string) needs to be the precise size in bytes.

Comment: _needs to be the precise size in bytes_ - now you contradict yourself. Strings contain chars and not bytes. `sizeof(char) == 2 * sizeof(byte)`

Comment: What I mean, is I want the ability to generate say 1kb of random text data. The size of individual characters is irrelevant.

Comment: It's rather easy to create a string that will take up a specific amount of bytes when encoded, but it sounds like you want to make a placeholder that will take up the same amount of bytes as an arbitrary string will take up, and that's impossible because that number of bytes will depend on what that string contains, and that is not known yet.

Comment: @Guffa That's not exactly the case. The random string will continue to fill the file after the point at which the string that replaces it ends.

Comment: @Razick: Ok, then it's easy. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) it may generate as many random bytes as you want. You can then convert it to string (e.g. using byte64 encoding or other method).

Remember to add `using System.Security.Cryptography;` to the file.

```
public class RandomService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp;

    public CryptoService()
    {
        rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();            
    }

    public byte[] GetRandomBytes(int length)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[length];
        rngCsp.GetBytes(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }

    public string GetRandomString(int length)
    {
        var numberOfBytesForBase64 = (int) Math.Ceiling((length*3)/4.0);
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(GetRandomBytes(numberOfBytesForBase64)).Substring(0, length); //might be longer because of padding            
        return base64String.Replace('+', '_').Replace('/', '-'); //we don't like these base64 characters
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        rngCsp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the size remain the same when it is converted to a string?

Comment: You get about 8/6 char per byte.

Comment: @Razick: base 64 is longer that initial byte array. Check my update - I've given sample code.

Comment: An RNG is very random but it also might be serious overkill for creating some test data. Even a problem if you need a lot of that data. `Random.NextBytes()' will probably work just as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: yes, that's true. I used this class in scenario where I needed cryptographically random data (specifically session ids). However, you may change GetRandomBytes implementation and leave GetRandomString for translation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This works very well, I'll try your suggestion and see if I get better speed though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not much speed improvement, but It's a bit cleaner so I'll use that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably take the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class, convert to `byte[]` and then `ToString()`

Comment: While every `string` can be converted to a `byte[]`, not every `byte[]` can be converted to a string.

Comment: @dtb: every byte[] is convertible to string (e.g. base64 or some arbitrary translation).

Comment: But like the name says, it only uses 64 different chars. There's more than that in a Unicode world.

Comment: 64 possible characters would actually be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] UsableChars = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', ...., `☺` };
Random r = new Random();

int wantedSize = 12;

string s = new string (Enumerable.Range(0, wantedSize)
    .Select((i) =>  UsableChars[r.Next(UsableChars.Length)]).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a limited set of characters, you can pick those that will end up as single byte codes regardless of the encoding used.

```
public byte[] CreateFiller(int length, Random rnd) {
  string chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(i => chars[rnd.Next(chars.Length)]).ToArray());
}

// only use the overload that creates a Random object itself if you use it once, not in a loop
public byte[] CreateFiller(int length) {
  return CreateFiller(length, new Random());
}
```